# Function to find cell with certain value in whole worksheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I've got a simple problem that I cannot seem to find a simple solution to. Basically what I want to do is have a formula that will find the first instance of a specific value (e.g "ADC") that occurs in a certain range (A1:Z1000), and give me the A1 notation for that cell's position in that sheet. I've tried Index&Match but that is column/row dependent, Regex, Find, etc. but none of those work. I just want it to go cell by cell and report back the absolute location (in the sheet) of the cell that has the first instance of that value. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
function NEEDLEINHAYSTACK(needle) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var r=rg.createTextFinder(needle).findNext();
  return r.getA1Notation();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Cooper! Is there any way to do this with a formula rather than Function if possible?